# Problem pushing heart-rate and spo2 data to Firebase using MAX30100

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp8266

I used Firebase for IoT and had some problems.

This my code:

```cpp
//Library for MAX30100
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"

//Library for Firebase
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

//Define for MAX30100 Sensor
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS 1000
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;

//Define for Firebase
#define FIREBASE_HOST "smart-hospitals-3idiots.firebaseio.com"

//databaseURL
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "ELelAN7pjOdN2csMi1QHLLnRe6uTqr00AsDXFIMw"
#define WIFI_SSID "TPlus"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "56482101"

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    //Connect to wifi.
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print("Connecting");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
    Serial.println("Firebase has started!");
    Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter...  ");

    if (!pox.begin()) {
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        for(;;);
    } else {
        Serial.println("SUCCESS");
    }

    pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
}

void loop() {
    pox.update();
    if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
        int heartbeat = (int) pox.getHeartRate();
        int spo2 = (int) pox.getSpO2();
        Serial.print("Heart: ");
        Serial.print(heartbeat);
        Serial.println(" BPM");
        Serial.print("SpO2:  ");
        Serial.print(spo2);
        Serial.println("%");
        Firebase.setInt("heartbeat",heartbeat);
        Firebase.setInt("spo2",spo2);
        tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```

When I run the code of the MAX30100 sensor, Serial (of Arduino) displays the correct input signal from the sensor. When I run the Firebase sample code, the data is also pushed to the Server in real time. However, when I run the code as image above, the sensor's signal is not received (even though the sensor has turned on), the display results are only zero, and the data is also pushed to the Server, but it is also zero. When I delete 2 lines "Firebase.setInt ()" in this code, the sensor still receives the signal as usual. I don't know what this is, I tried searching on Google but still can't find results.

I use WIFI ESP8266 Node MCU Lua D1 Mini and MAX30100 Sensor.

Similar problems ( https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=621499.0 ) , but I still have not found the answer :<

Hope to get help from you. Thank you very very very much
Sorry for not knowing the format code ...

Comment: Image for code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZBUPWHAHR0we2m3478049mXOl199Asw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: T.T No one comment

Comment: I am facing same issue. did you get any solution?